# How is tenure-track start-up in Europe?

Tags: funding, tenure-track, assistant-professor

After 2 postdoc positions, I applied for tenure-track assistant professor positions. I am from mechanical engineering and my research is strongly experimental. This is critically important for me to have a considerable start-up package to run my lab to get funds and students.

In two interviews for positions in the USA and Japan, I was told that the start-up package is about $800K, with a possibility to be negotiated to reach 1 million too (not Japan).

However, in an interview for a position in the UK, I was told that stat-up package in not part of the position (though it is a normal faculty position, not teaching only). They can offer up to 200K pounds, subject to approval.

I am very interested in Europe, but it made me wonder if this is the common situation in Europe or this position was exceptional?

Do European university normally offer start-up package for building a lab (in experimental fields) for a new assistant professor? I mean, as it is common in the United States. Or European universities have a different scheme for funding new faculty members.

I am referring to the Western Europe: Mainly UK, and also Germany and Scandinavia.

Comment: I feel like the appropriate answer is going to be extremely dependent on the country and maybe even specific institutions

Comment: @posdef I don't think so. In the US, almost any research university I know have similar start-up packages. Some have more through endowed positions. I mentioned that my question is about UK. Thought that western European university should be similar. I am not talking about exception, but the common strategy.

Comment: Not even different faculties in my university (in Sweden) have a common strategy about tenure-track, let along different universities in the country.

Comment: *In the US, almost any research university I know have similar start-up packages* Academia in general **varies greatly** from a European country to another. Even within, say, Switzerland, there is no consensus on the 'start up package' in fact such a thing does not necessarily exist in every institution. Even tenure-track is not the dominant model for pre-tenured faculty positions.

Comment: In Italy, they don't give you anything. You should bootstrap yourself ;-)

Comment: I think the most common tenure-track model in Europe is *"what the heck is tenure track?"*. Packages are common, but primarily for Full Professors, and there they are quite freely negotiated.

Comment: @user33230 Well, the USA is a single country while Europe is composed of dozens of countries, and some universities have been around for much longer than the USA has even existed. European universities are bound to have developed a few differences between each others...

Comment: OK, so maybe not every European university system uses tenure or tenure-track positions when it recruits faculty, but we must be able to help OP to understand the models they do use and whether start-up packages are common for entry-level faculty hires in experimental STEM fields or what mechanisms they might use to bring on new experimental resources.

Comment: Huh, on what kind of map is scandinavia in Western Europe ?... It's obviously Northern Europe.

Comment: In STEM field an $800k startup in Japan is EXTREMELY generous. It is like order(s) of magnitude more than I have ever seen in leading Japanese universities / high profile governmental programs for assoc. prof level research positions. So I am not sure your other experiences were average in any sense.

Answer (score 16):

I think the issue is that the concept of "tenure-track" doesn't really exist in many European countries—at least not as it's interpreted in the US. Consequently, start-up packages can be difficult to compare.

When I started my present position, I got a very small package, if you reckoned it in terms of what's needed to buy equipment and pay for travel. On the other hand, I was guaranteed two full-time scientific positions for the lifetime of my appointment. (These positions could be used for either PhD students or postdocs.) Reckoned in that sense, however, the package is quite generous (close to $1 million).

In other nearby countries (Netherlands, for instance), the support is not nearly so strong: typically just one student supported by the university, and relatively limited budgets.

Comment: Sounds like you got a pretty sweet deal! :)

Comment: That's a *great* deal for a Juniorprofessor. I think most Juniorprofessors have exactly 0 package.

Answer (score 6):

Bit late to this, but thought I'd add something to it as it was a question I had when I first made the jump to PI.

I'm sure it is field specific, so I can only answer for my field - molecular biology.

Firstly, tenure, in the US sense is not just uncommon in the UK, it does not exist for new hires. It was abolished by law in the 80s. There are a few tenured professors left who got it before the abolition, but there are fewer every year.

Start up packages: In the UK, in my field at least, large start up packages are fairly rare. When I took my job the deal was: little cash, but if there is a particular piece of kit you literally can't do your work without, we will consider it.

In the end my deal was: £10K in cash to spend as I saw fit and a 3.5 year PhD studentship with a total of £15K research and training support grant (RTSG). Calling around others I knew in the same field who had got their jobs recently, it seemed that this was pretty standard, if not a little on the generous side.

As for how you are supposed to fund your research? Roll up your sleeves and apply for government grants. Success rates are currently 15%, and to keep your (non-tenure) job, you'll be needing one within the first three years. Oh and in the UK you can't resubmit a grant that overlaps with something you've submitted before.

Comment: @lan Sudbery: what is common for the Uk instead of tenure track? What position the people normally have at the beginning of their job as a teacher at universities (after postdoc)? What is it called?

Comment: @m123 there are basically two ways in.  The position i describe above is a lectureship.  That is the closest match to a US style tenure track position at an R01. The alternative is an independent fellowship.  Here you are entirely funded (salary and research costs) by an external funder.  Many universities will promise you an open ended (research and teaching) 
 contract at the end if you bring your fellowship to their university.

Comment: @lan Sudbery: Thanks.